# Share screen on Mac/iPhone without having Apple TV

Tags: macos, iphone, mac, appletv, screen-sharing

I am gonna to have a telephone with my customer to present our first milestone of one app we are building for customer (I am a PO). I have to call him by telephone and I want to share my iphone screen via Mac in realtime. I googled and there is AirPlay with Apply TV. But I don't have Apple TV.

Is there any alternative way I can do that? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can connect the iPhone to Mac via USB and then open **QuickTime**. There's **New Movie Recording** -> Select iPhone as a video source. Then You can simply share Your Mac screen with the customer.

[image]